# In Stata, how can I only keep observations that have outcomes in every time period for every ID?

Tags: stata

This is a followup post for @NickCox with a better example. I have a dataset on multiple outcome for individuals in two groups that were treated (or not treated) by an intervention at three time points. However, not every individual has complete data for each measure at each time point. Also, data from group 1 was only measured at times 1 and 2, and data from group 2 was only measured at time 2 and 3.

| id | depression_outcome | group | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 14 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | . | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 13 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | . | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 11 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | . | 2 | 3 |

How do I exclude IDs that do not have an outcome in both periods? I only want to see how outcomes changed between groups over time for observations have data in all periods. In this example, I'd only want to retain IDs 1 and 3. After this data cleaning, I will use the mixed command in Stata to conduct an analysis.

Comment: @NickCox here is an updated example. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is your data example shown using `dataex`, which was requested in your previous post.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(id depression_outcome group time)
1 10 1 1
1  8 1 2
2 14 1 1
2  . 1 2
3 13 2 2
3  7 2 3
4  . 2 2
4  6 2 3
5 11 2 2
5  . 2 3
end
```

It seems that you want `id`s if and only if they have non-missing values at two distinct times. If so, consider this code:

```
drop if missing(depression)

bysort id (time) : keep if time[1] != time[_N]

list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------------+
     | id   depres~e   group   time |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |  1         10       1      1 |
  2. |  1          8       1      2 |
     |------------------------------|
  3. |  3         13       2      2 |
  4. |  3          7       2      3 |
     +------------------------------+
```